# How to make the marquee style of progress bar?

Tags: c++, mfc, progress-bar, marquee

I need to do the progress bar with marquee style. But I'd no idea how to start with the code. I need to run the progress bar while my loop is running, so when the loop stop, the progress bar also will stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the [CProgressCtrl::SetMarquee](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cprogressctrl-class#setmarquee) class member to turn marquee mode on or off. You can call this at any time (after the control has been created).